# Android studio - stop immediate errors-checking in classes & xml

Tags: android, performance, syntax-error

I'm developing on Android Studio & testing on Emulator at the same time, and as you know that Android Studio is checking for syntax-errors & misspellings while you're writing, and due to this my processor "works his fingers to the bone".

So, I wondered if it's possible to prevent android studio from that immediate checking until I do it manually. It will be great for performance!

Cheers!

Comment: try disabling linter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file>>Power Save Mode

Enabling Power-save mode available in the file menu will disable code insight and background tasks.Hope this helps...